# filtering nullable data in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgresql `coupon` table with fields `id :: bigint not null` and `max_usages :: bigint`.

The query

```
select id, max_usages from coupon where id = 1;
```

returns one row

```
 id | max_usages 
----+------------
  1 |
```

as expected.

It's also expected that

```
select id, max_usages from coupon where id = 1 and max_usages = 1;
```

returns no rows.

What puzzles me is that the queries

```
select id, max_usages from coupon where id = 1 and max_usages != 1;
```

and

```
select id, max_usages from coupon where id = 1 and max_usages = NULL;
```

also return no rows.

How can this be? Isn't the `max_usages` value equal to `NULL` and henceforth different from 1?

I'm using Postgresql 15.3

Comment: See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp